# How to multiselect more than one listbox simultaneously in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, multi-select

**Scenario**

I have two listboxes named `openItemList` and `serialNumber`. `serialNumber` entries are unique numbers for every row of `openItemList`. It means every `openItemList` has a unique `serialNumber`. But `openItemList` can have duplicate values in different rows.  User can understand only `openItemList` and they select this. Since respective `serialNumber` also select based on `openItemList` selection, my program is finding related row data by using `serialNumber` as search word criteria and update the correct row accordingly.

Currently I am able to select both listboxes simultaneously because, I set multiselect property to single entry. I use following code to do so

```
Private Sub openItemList_Click()
    serialNumber.ListIndex = openItemList.ListIndex
End Sub

Private Sub openItemList_Scroll()
    serialNumber.TopIndex = openItemList.TopIndex
End Sub

Private Sub serialNumber_Click()
    openItemList.ListIndex = serialNumber.ListIndex
End Sub

Private Sub serialNumber_Scroll()
    openItemList.TopIndex = serialNumber.TopIndex
End Sub
```

**Current Problem**

Now I want to let user to select multiple rows in the listbox so that user can update multiple rows at once. The moment I changed property of the two listbox to `MultiSelectExtended`, the selection dependency is no more working. Due to this, I cannot search the respective rows based on `serialNumber` anymore. Anyone knows how to select both listbox simultaneously when change to `MultiSelectExtended` mode?

Currently this is how the two listboxes behave. The moment I choose one listbox, the respective value of the other listbox highlight as well.

[image]

The moment I change to Multiselect, it is acting as below without any simultaneous selection

[image]

Comment: If the listbox in on your worksheet then; right click the list box, Select Format Control, Under the Control tab-Select Multi.

Comment: If the listbox is on a UserForm then: In the visual basic window Select the listbox on the userform and under Properties, change the MultiSelect option

Comment: @GMalc I know that. As I mentioned in the question, when I do multi select option enabled in properties window, that is where I am loosing the dependency of the two list boxes. My issue is about the dependency of the two list boxes at the same time. Not about selecting multiple items individually.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to:

- use `Change` event instead of `Click` one
- match both listboxes each element `Selected` property:

as follows:

```
Private Sub openItemList_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    With openItemList
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            serialNumber.Selected(i) = .Selected(i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

also, change `openItemList_Scroll()` to `openItemList_MouseDown()` to pair listboxes visible elements

Comment: wow...This works perfect. Thank you. By the way I tried another work around by using one listbox and show both serial Number and item names in the same listbox and extract serial number by giving some specific separator while listing and then use Split technique